# Delete with unlink() from database with uploaded location in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have an error when trying to unlink my files from local disk :

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $name = $_POST['deleteEntryName'];
    $query = "select name,image from image where name =  '".$name."' ";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            $delQuery = "delete from image where name = '".$name."' ";
            $delResult = $db->query($delQuery);
            $delPath = $query['image'];
            unlink($delPath);
            alert("File successfully deleted");
            redirect("newEntry.php");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("File is not exist");
            redirect("newEntry.php");
        }
}
?>
```

where image is  the path of my image :

```
    $path = "upload/". $picture_name;

    move_uploaded_file($picture_tmp,$path)

    $insQuery = "insert into image(name,image,price,description) values('".$name."','".$path."','".$price."','".$desc."')";
```

i get the " illegal string offset 'image' error , and no file exist error.
why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong variable. The right one would be the fetched result from mysqli, but you don't do it yet.

When using fetch_assoc() (for mysqli, for pdo it's just fetch()) you don't have to call num_rows as the fetch_assoc returns null if there is no row.

```
$name = $_POST['deleteEntryName'];
// WARNING: Possible SQL Injection here!
$query = "select name,image from image where name =  '".$name."' ";
// mysqli::query() returns a statement
$selStmt = $db->query($query);
// mysqli::fetch_assoc() returns an array with your columns
if ($selResult = $selStmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $delQuery = "delete from image where name = '".$name."' ";
        $delResult = $db->query($delQuery);
        $delPath = $selResult['image']; // change here
        unlink($delPath);
        alert("File successfully deleted");
        redirect("newEntry.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong,

```
$delPath = $query['image'];
```

Change to

```
$delPath = $result['image'];
```

And also this will njot work,

```
alert("File successfully deleted");
redirect("newEntry.php");
```

Comment: actually i tried that, and the error is more confusing

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: try using `$result->image`;

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $name = $_POST['deleteEntryName'];
    $query = "select name,image from image where name =  '".$name."' ";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            $delQuery = "delete from image where name = '".$name."' ";
            $delResult = $db->query($delQuery);
            $delPath = $row['image'];
            unlink($delPath);
            echo "<script>alert("File successfully deleted")</script>";
            redirect("newEntry.php");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("File is not exist");
            redirect("newEntry.php");
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `Illegal string offset 'image'` means that you are using the string `'image'` as an offset to another string. In this case, because you were trying to find the path in the wrong variable:

```
$query = "select name,image from image where name =  '".$name."' ";
// …
$delPath = $query['image']; // Error: Works for arrays, not strings.
```